# Postfix Header_check using Regexp

Tags: postfix

Postfix regexp is not working when I use this:

```
/^Subject:Open your $Bank account  /                REJECT
```

But when I use like below Subject it is working:

```
/^Subject:.*($Bank|account) /                    REJECT
```

How do I match the exact Subject using regexp?

Comment: Please provide the exact header you're trying to match, otherwise we're just guessing what it looks like.

Comment: From: <test@example.com>
To: <new@example.com>
Date: Sun, 3 Feb 2013 08:19:34 +0100
Subject: Open your $Bank account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a space after `Subject:` which your regex is missing.

```
/^Subject: Open your $Bank account/                REJECT
```

Note there are also spaces at the end of your regex which I removed from the one above.